# Splitting a string with parentheses in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a string in the following format:

```
(1.2,2.3),(4.5,6.7),(8.9,1.2)
```

and so on. I want to traverse the string and create a list with the values. Each node in the list consists of 2 fields, say A and B.

list.A=1.2
list.B=2.3

2nd node

list.A=4.5
list.B=6.7

How can I do this?

Comment: Use pattern `-?\\d+` to find the numbers in your string

Comment: with java? that is possible...

Comment: No attempts so far? :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
String s = "(1.2,2.3),(4.5,6.7),(8.9,1.2)";

System.out.println(Arrays.asList( s.replaceAll("[()]", "").split(",")));
```

#### Output

```
[1.2, 2.3, 4.5, 6.7, 8.9, 1.2]
```

Comment: this can be for your old answer `split("[(),]+")` ...although updated is better answer.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan With `split("[(),]+")` the first element in the returned array is empty.

Comment: hmm... and for last time too. it returns `['', '1.2', '2.3', '4.5', '6.7', '8.9', '1.2', '']` .. present answer is better